# Problems to inject Repository when data-jpa dep is on

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jdbc

I noticed, as soon as I un-comment JPA dep, see below:

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
//implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
I do not have any @Entity annotated classes in my code.
```

I got an error on start:

```
The bean 'myRepository', defined in null, could not be registered. A bean with that name has already been defined in null and overriding is disabled.
```

Actually I got this error for all my repositories on start, randomly it just fails on first it could not start and stops. I.e. there is no risk that I actually do some duplicated in repositories.

I use:     `id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.0.RELEASE'` version

I did `gradlew clean build` of the project to make sure I don't have any leftover.

My repository class is:

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyModel, UUID> {

    @Query(rowMapperClass = MyModelRowMapper.class, value = "select my_uuid, my_code from my_model_table")
    Iterable<MyModel> findMyStuff();
}
```

where is MyModel

```
public class MyModel {

    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private String code; ...
```

All works if I keep `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` commented.

Wonder, if there is a bug or I still [missed to setup something](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/#jdbc.repositories).

I got my

```
@Configuration
@EnableJdbcRepositories
public class RepositoryConfig {
}
```

sitting in the same package as all repositories live.

And after all, it works if I don't include jpa. I do not have any JPA specific code in my code yet.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that the different repositories are only handled by the correct Spring Data Module, by moving them and the respective `@EnableXXXRepositories` annotation to separate packages or by providing appropriate filters to the annotation.

Otherwise Spring Data will try to create repositories of the wrong kind which then will fail, for example because no matching `@Id` annotation is found.

Comment: if I create a folder "jdbc" put there the config class with  @ EnableJdbcRepositories  and move all my data jdbc repositories there "to be in one module". I still have the same exception. IF run from the integration test.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the cause of this is but I'm seeing that on upgrading to Spring Boot 3.2.0 the `JdbcMappingContext` is failing to determine parameter names for the default constructor of an entity.

It's kind of random which constructor Spring data determines as the default constructor so we were getting this error for some of our entities and not others.

The workaround I came up with was to add a no-arg constructor annotated `@PersistenceCreator` to all of our entities.