# Spring DATA JDBC fails to inject a Repository when run from the spring integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jdbc

[Spring Boot JDBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-jdbc) with `Spring Boot`: 2.2.4.RELEASE, in gradle the dep:

```
 implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
```

The dep to -data-jpa (see "duplicated question")

```
//implementation ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") is commented
```

Got this error ONLY when run it from the integration tests:

```
    "A constructor parameter name must not be null to be used with Spring Data JDBC!"
 Error creating bean with name 'myRepository':
```

where my repository is defined as this. An interface. It can not have a constructor.

```
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyData, UUID> {
```

the way it is injected is:

```
@Inject
MyRepository myRepository;
```

The integration test itself:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, classes = Application.class)
public class MyResourceTest {
```

It used to work for a lower spring boot version from the tests.
It works Ok. from IDE when starting tests.
It works Ok. when starting the app and hit the endpoints - it does inject the repositories.

**Q:** How to make Spring DATA JDBC work without this "A constructor parameter name must not be null to be used with Spring Data JDBC!" error for the spring data jdbc repositories?

**UPDATE:** just checked and double-checked.

```
class MyData {
    //@Id Dont use the Id annotation here because I use a mapper when @Query(.. by this object 
    private UUID id;
    private String name;
    private MyData2 mydata2;

    public MyData() {}
    public MyData(String name, MyData2 mydata2) {...}
    .. all getters and setters
}
```

`MyData2` is the same - with the default + all arg Constructor. All is made manual. No `lombok`.

**Update 2:**

if I create a folder "jdbc" put there the config class with `@ EnableJdbcRepositories` and move all my data jdbc repositories there "to be in one module". I still have the same exception. IF run from the integration test.

Comment: Please post the source of the class MyData

Comment: updated. it has the default + all arg constructor + all getters settlers, set manually no Lombok. after all, it works in general. it does not only from the tests.

Comment: can't find the cause, but found the templated source, where the text of your error is mentioned https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jdbc/blob/36b419e712fbb792c0396a859f72099fafb21adf/spring-data-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jdbc/core/convert/BasicJdbcConverter.java

Comment: Can you just try it with the default constructor only?

Comment: same. this question is actually a duplicated of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58476286/problems-to-inject-repository-when-data-jpa-dep-is-on (forgot about it. but this is more specific - it fails in tests only))

Comment: will switch to plain jdbc-template. too risky. (seems not many folks use it for now).

Comment: Having an id (with an actual `@Id` annotation) is kind of a requirement for using repositories. If you don't have that, you probably don't have an aggregate and therefore `JdbcTemplate` seems like the better choice.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace. I find currently confusing that something seems to try to load an entity which shouldn't happen during initialisation of repositories. The stack trace should show where this call is coming from.